# Replacing any "not number" variable by +Infinity

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of elements. Some of them are numbers (float, int etc, possibly numpy). Some other are not.

Is it possible to automatically replace in this list any not number by +Infinity for instance ?

So that if I want to take the min of this list whatever the type of this "not number" is, it will ignore it during the computation ?

I would like the easiest way to do this.

**When I say "not number type" I don't mean it is a NaN. I mean it is anything that is not a number (a string, an array, a Nan, whatever).**

Comment: Why not just remove them? Could you show us some example data and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you're making your own rules here, your best bet is to write a *key function* for this.

```py
import math
import numbers

def number_ranks(n):
    if not isinstance(n, numbers.Number):
        return math.inf
    else:
        return n

data = [0,5,3,'foo', 10, {}, 1.0]
print(min(data, key=number_ranks))
# 0
print(sorted(data, key=number_ranks))
# [0, 1.0, 3, 5, 10, 'foo', {}]
```

Though, what you may want to do instead filter the original data set. It depends on the behavior you want.

```py
min(
    filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, numbers.Number), data)
)
```

This will make it as if those values did not exist at all in the original sequence, as opposed to changing their sorted rank.

One difference here is that you guarantee your result won't include non-numbers (and that you'll get an error in the case of `min` with a sequence of only non-numbers, for example)

```py
data = ['foo', {}]
min(data, key=number_ranks)
# 'foo'
# ^ this may not be what you want

list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, numbers.Number), data))
# []
min(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, numbers.Number), data))
# ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Note that `math.nan` is considered an instance of `Number`. So, again, if you're making more complex rules, make a function that lays out those rules how you want it.

```py
def actual_numbers(n):
    if not isinstance(n, numbers.Number):
        return False
    if n in (math.nan, math.inf, -math.inf):
        return False
    return True

min(filter(actual_numbers, data))
```

Comment: IMO, `filter(lambda)` is ugly. Use a generator expression instead: `min(x for x in data if isinstance(x, numbers.Number))`. For `list(filter(lambda))`, use a list comprehension instead: `[x for x in data if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]`